Docker compose launched through Python's subprocess.Popen is still responding to CTRL-C even though I've overridden the signal handler
I'm trying to launch Docker Compose as a subprocess in Python with subprocess.Popen. I've overridden the signal handler for the parent script and the subprocess, but Compose is still responding to CTRL-C.
def pre_exec():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

try:
    # block SIGINT in the parent script
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    process = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'compose', 'up'], env=env_vars, preexec_fn=pre_exec)
    process.wait()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred running Compose: {e}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

I believe this code should do nothing if CTRL-C is pressed, but when I run it, Compose is still responding to the CTRL-C and shutting down.
I can tell the parent script is correctly ignoring it, because without the initial signal handler, the script exits to the shell while compose finishes shutting down. It seems like the compose subprocess is somehow ignoring the signal handler registration.

Docker may have its own SIGINT handler, which overrides what it inherits from the parent. There's not much you can do about this.
